# pgAdmin4 connects to all databases

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

When I connect to a server with pgAdmin4 v6.20 and check the connections to the server, I see pgAdmin4 having a connection each to all databases of the server. This makes problems when I want to delete a database manually.

Why does it do that and how can I revert this to pgAdmin III behaviour?

Comment: When you closed pgAdmin4 last, were there open panels into those databases, which it is now re-opening?

Comment: I see similar behaviour, in the logs (the user has no access to the other databases). In that case it is clear that no previous connections existed.

Comment: This was a bug in pgAdmin4 v6: https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/5919

Answer (score 1):

pgAdmin will only establish a connection to the database you specified as "maintenance database" in the connection settings. You can terminate that connection with "disconnect from server".

In addition, pgAdmin will connect to any database that you select or expand in the tree view. There is "disconnect from database" to deal with that.

If you don't click on anything inside pgAdmin, it won't establish any database connections. It only connects if it needs a connection to provide the information you ask it for.

Comment: This is pgAdmin III behaviour. I asked why pgAdmin 4 does this differently. Or does YOUR pgAdmin 4 behave that way also? I am using pgAdmin 4 v6.20

Comment: Last time i checked (which is not very often), pgAdmin 4 behaved like that.